# Is there a way to generate ints using i?

Tags: java

I have a homework assignment which I'm probably making too much of...

It reads two columns of doubles from a file and finds the average of each one. (haven't gotten there yet.)

I can't seem to get the array lists to act like I want, so I was thinking, "what if I used `i` to generate all the `int`s I need?"

Something like:

`while (in.hasNextLine)
                   {
                   double dub(i) = (double) in.Next;
}`

and when `in.hasNextLine = false`, it stops allocating `int`s. Until then
dub1, dub2, dub3, and up until `hasNextLine=false`.

Is this something that is doable? The sentinel is there to keep it from running away with all the RAM.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: You probably should read on ["array"](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/14array/) or better [java collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Comment: That won't work. Use an array or an ArrayList.

Comment: Can you guys who are downvoting at least explain the down votes? "Stupid question, obviously new to coding" uh..yeah, that is why I am asking questions, TO LEARN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend just making a list of doubles. I don't know if what you want to do is possible in Java.

Like so:

```
List<Double> dubs = new ArrayList<>();
while (in.hasNextLine)
{
     dubs.add((double) in.next());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I tried to have it do. 
I must have an error someplace else in the code. 
You exactly answered what I was asking -- is this possible. Probably not. I appreciate the reply rather than hate.